# A* 8 puzzle running time takes too long

Tags: java, a-star, heuristics

im sorry if this is a long question, but im not sure if my A* 8 puzzle java code works or not... i found out that my code runs just fine for simple inputs (easy to average cases), but i don't know if it works in worst case scenarios...

i tried modifying my code to use manhattan distances of each node to use as my heuristics function and my code works even on the worst case, but it just takes too long... and when i use "number of misplaced tiles" as my heuristics function, my code takes longer to run simple to average cases compared to using manhattan distances. it also does not produce a solution for worst case scenarios even after 15 minutes...

Note: at worst case, an 8 puzzle is solvable by no more than 31 steps...

... Here is my main function for my code:

```
    List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodeList.add(startNode); //"Node startNode" contains the root node of the tree that will be produced
    Node currentNode = null;
    while (1 == 1) {            
        //THIS SECTION FINDS THE LEAF NODE WITH THE LEAST f(n)
        currentNode = null;
        for (Node pickNode : nodeList) {
            if (pickNode.isLeaf == true) {
                if (currentNode == null)
                    currentNode = pickNode;

                else if (pickNode.fn < currentNode.fn){
                    currentNode = pickNode;
                }
            }
        }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/ 
        //BREAK THE LOOP WHEN THE SOLUTION IS FOUND
        if (Arrays.deepEquals(currentNode.state, goalState))
            break;
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/     
        else {
            int xcheck = currentNode.zeroX;
            int ycheck = currentNode.zeroY;
            int switcher;
            int approve = 1;
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/ 
             //THE FOLLOWING LINES DETERMINES WHICH CHILDREN CAN BE PRODUCED BY A NODE
             if ((ycheck - 1) >= 0) {
                int subState[][] = new int [3][];
                subState[0] = currentNode.state[0].clone();
                subState[1] = currentNode.state[1].clone();
                subState[2] = currentNode.state[2].clone();
                switcher = subState[ycheck-1][xcheck];
                subState[ycheck-1][xcheck] = 0;
                subState[ycheck][xcheck] = switcher;

                Node checkerNode = new Node();
                checkerNode = currentNode;
                while (checkerNode != null) {
                    if (Arrays.deepEquals(subState, checkerNode.state)) {
                        approve = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    checkerNode = checkerNode.parentNode;
                }

                if (approve != 0) {
                    Node childNode = new Node();
                    childNode.state = subState;
                    childNode.totalPath = currentNode.totalPath + "*" + "up";
                    childNode.gn = currentNode.gn + 1;
                    childNode.hn = computeHn(childNode.state, goalState);
                    childNode.fn = childNode.gn + childNode.hn;
                    childNode.isLeaf = true;
                    childNode.parentNode = currentNode;
                    childNode.zeroX = xcheck;
                    childNode.zeroY = ycheck-1;
                    nodeList.add(childNode);
                }
            }
            approve = 1;
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
            if ((ycheck + 1) <= 2) {
                //same logic with: if (ycheck-1 >= 0)
            }
            approve = 1;
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
            if ((xcheck + 1) <= 2) {
                //same logic with: if (ycheck-1 >= 0)
            }
            approve = 1;
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
            if ((xcheck - 1) >= 0) {
                //same logic with: if (ycheck-1 >= 0)
            }
            approve = 1;
        }
        currentNode.isLeaf = false;
    }
```

Here is the function that computes for my heuristics (number of misplaced tiles instead of Manhattan distance):

```
public static int computeHn (int checkStateH[][], int goalStateH[][]) {
    int total = 0;
    int rowC = 0;
    int columnC = 0;

        rowC = 0;
        while (rowC < 3) {
            columnC = 0;
            while (columnC < 3) {
                if (goalStateH[rowC][columnC] != checkStateH[rowC][columnC]) {
                    total++;
                }
                columnC++;
            }

            rowC++;
        }

    return total;
}
```

and here is my Node class:

```
public class Node {
   int state[][]; //contains the matrix configuration of the node
   String totalPath; //contains the path on how to get to this node from the root node
   int gn; //contains the number of moves made to get to this node from the root node
   int hn; //contains the heuristic (number of misplaced tiles per node)
   int fn; // fn = gn + hn
   boolean isLeaf; //states whether a node is a leaf or not. used so that I can know whether a node could still be expanded or not 
   Node parentNode; //points to the node's parent node
   int zeroX; //the x position of the zero tile
   int zeroY; //the y position of the zero tile
}
```

This is the given matrix,  or the "start state" matrix (on worst case, this could be answered by 31 moves at minimum):

- 8 0 6
- 5 4 7
- 2 3 1

... and it should reach this end state:

- 0 1 2
- 3 4 5
- 6 7 8

... again, when i use "manhattan distance" as my heuristics function, my code works, but it takes 30 secs to produce an answer for this kind of input... but when i use "number of misplaced tiles" as my heuristics function, it does not produce a solution even after 15 minutes, but gives an answer when i use this matrix instead:

- 5 8 6
- 2 7 1
- 3 0 4  //this matrix is reachable from the previously mentioned start state matrix

... thanks for those who will help!... i'm sorry if its kinda long, but i thought i should post my code instead of just stating the logic of my code since i might have made errors in implementing my logic...

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that Manhattan Distance would be faster, since it's a better heuristic. 30 seconds is a bit of a long time to wait for a solution, especially for C++, but it's not utterly ridiculous. >15 minutes is, though, even for a not-great heuristic.

If I'm interpreting your code correctly, the `checkerNode` loop is checking to see if this state is already present in the path you're currently exploring by traversing the entire path. This is fairly inefficient (O(log(n)ish), I think). If you instead maintain a dictionary of states that you've already expanded, you can get this down to constant time.

There might be other subtle inefficiencies, but I suspect that that will speed up your code substantially.

EDIT to explain dictionaries:

A dictionary is a data structure that allows you to very quickly look up whether an element is present or not.

For most data structures, if you want to find an element with a given value, you have to compare that value to every element already stored in the structure (like how you're comparing checkerNode to all of the predecessor nodes). The problem is, as you store more and more things in your data structure, this process takes longer and longer. This is not the case with a dictionary, because a dictionary uses something called a hashtable to immediately go to the location where a given element would be stored if it existed. Then, if the element is there, you know that it is in the data structure, and if it's not you know it isn't.

Dictionaries are usually used to map a given key to an associated value, but here we don't really care about that functionality. We just want to know if a given key is in the dictionary, so we can set the value to whatever we want (usually I just store the boolean value "True", or a pointer to the node if you'll need to be able to find it again). In C++, the built-in dictionary class is [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

To use it in your code you can do something roughly like this:

First, initialize the map object

```
std::map<char,int> already_explored;
```

Execute the start of program until the point where a value has just been assigned to currentNode. Now that we are exploring currentNode, we add it's state to the dictionary. The state is the key, "True" is the value.

```
already_explored[currentNode.state] = True;
```

Continue executing the program until you've found the next state are want to know if it's already been seen. Now we can do a look-up in the dictionary:

```
if (already_explored.count(subState) > 0){
    approve = 0;
}
```

If you do things in this order, you never even have to worry about checking the f(n) values of other nodes with the same states. The first one that A* reaches is guaranteed to be the fastest way to reach that state. And there will never be any benefit to taking a longer path to the same state.

Comment: oh, checkerNode only checks if the childNode that will be produced will have a state that is the same with its parent/ancestors. if it does, then the childNode will not be produced anymore...

Comment: sorry this might be a stupid question, but what do you mean by "dictionary of states"? is it a list of some sort? or could i make use of my nodeList, where i will traverse nodeList and check whether the childNode that will be produced will have a same state with another existing node (whether it is a leaf or not), and if that node with the same state has less f(n) than the childNode that will be produced, abort the production of childNode...? :(

Comment: That's not a stupid question at all. I edited my answer to better explain dictionaries and how to use one here. It's kind of like traversing nodeList, but much faster.

I'm happy to provide more clarification if it still doesn't make sense :).

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look to your code, I can point two things that might improve a lot the efficiency of your code:

1. A* stores an ordered list with the nodes to be expanded (the OPEN list), which is sorted by ascending `f(n)`. In your code I understand that you are selecting the node with the lowest `f(n)` in the first loop, traversing the tree of all generated states. This is very inefficient because the search tree grows with each iteration of the algorithm, while you only need to iterate over the leafs of that tree (which are the ones that have been generated as successors of other states but not expanded). It's better for you to store the nodes which are going to be expanded by A* in a `PriorityQueue`. The first element of the queue is the one with lowest `f(n)`, so you do not have to traverse all the search tree in each iteration.
2. As @seaotternerd points in his answer, you need to maintain somehow a "dictionary" with the states already expanded by the algorithm. A* stores in the OPEN list the nodes which are generated as successors of other ones (but not expanded yet), and in the CLOSED list the nodes already expanded. This is needed to check, in the case of reaching a state wich has been generated in previous iterations, if you have improved it's `f(n)` or not.
   As an example, if you follow this [implementation of A*](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/development/hipster-core/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/algorithm/AStar.java) done in the [Hipster](http://hipster4j.org) library, the following fields will be used to store your "dictionary" of states:

   ```
   private Map<int[][], Node> open;
   private Map<int[][], Node> closed;
   private Queue<Node> queue;
   ```

   Then you could query the OPEN list to retrieve the node with lowest `f(n)` using this method:

   ```
   private Node takePromising() {
       // Poll until a valid state is found
       Node node = queue.poll();
       while (!open.containsKey(node.state())) {
           node = queue.poll();
       }
       return node;
   }
   ```

EDITED:
 This will avoid you to iterate along the search tree as you are doing now at the beginning of your loop, improving the selection of the most promising node up to `O(n)`. With the dictionary, the code that you are executing in `checkerNode` to avoid the loop "ancestor-successor-ancestor" will not be neccessary anymore. And take into account that without a proper implementation of the OPEN and CLOSED lists your search might be entering in infinite loops. To finish, you might find interesting to check the [full example of the 8-puzzle problem solved with A*](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/development/hipster-examples/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/examples/EightPuzzleProblemExample.java) which comes included in the [Hipster library](http://hipster4j.org).

I hope my answer helps,

Comment: tldr; the posted/question code is not following A* - if it were the solution would be found in milliseconds.